# CURL Request crashes SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I've noticed a little problem with CURL in PHP. Whenever I request a `https://` connection it returns "false", and every website that I try to reach while I have my PHP page open reports to have an Untrusted certificate.

This is my request method:

```
private function request($url, $params, $method = "GET") {
        if ($method == "GET")
            $url = $this->structGET($url, $params);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.');
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

        $header[] = 'Accept-Language: EN';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        if ($method == "POST") {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            if ($params)
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        }
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

And this is what Chrome returns when I try visiting Facebook.

> **The site's security certificate is not trusted!**
>
> You attempted to reach
>   www.facebook.com, but the server presented a certificate issued by an
>   entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This
>   may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials,
>   which Google Chrome cannot rely on for identity information, or an
>   attacker may be trying to intercept your communications. You cannot
>   proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security
>   for this domain.

Comment: "*[...] every website that I try to reach while I have my PHP page open reports to have an Untrusted certificate*". Could you clarify, what does the fact that you're visiting your own page have to do with what you get when visiting Facebook directly using your browser? What happens with other browsers, other machines? Do you administer your own machine? Are you on a corporate network?

Comment: Every website that uses https://*
It gives me the same error in every browser for every SSL website.

Comment: Only on your machines? Are you on a corporate network? What about other machines on that network?

Comment: Only on my machine, the server is local.

Comment: And I guess it wasn't installed centrally, like the other machines on that network?

Comment: No, it's my personal laptop. I doubt I could get the administrator's certificates, since I'm a student.

Comment: Certificates are not secret, you could easily try to find out which one the CA certificate is (by looking at the top of the chain in the certificate details when browsing with a centrally installed machine) and install it on your own machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that happens when cURL tries to see if the SSL is verified. Facebook usually has a verified signature but may be because of network, it is returning invalid (happens in my case: using fortiguard proxy, facebook blocked!)

So, what you can do is, you can choose to ignore that error totally.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

That should fix it. But, if you want to fix it **properly**, then you should probably use a proxy or something or get a certificate for the server(if it is yours).

Comment: Disabling certificate verification introduces a MITM-attack vulnerability, which goes precisely against the reason why services like Facebook try to force HTTPS.

Comment: @Bruno hey, but if the ssl was not verified, then it is a problem existing in the network. Nobody can **FIX** that right? The OP would know what the problem is (if he understood what chrome said) and so he has no other option except changing his network OR having a trade off and working with no verification. I think -1 is unfair because I mentioned that this isn't a proper fix!

Comment: This fixes the problem. It seems it's a network problem as well. It works fine on my home network.

Comment: @goldenparrot, ignoring a potential MITM is never a good idea. If it's a legitimate MITM proxy, add its CA cert to your trusted list. Don't develop code that ignores verification instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use techniques that disable certificate verification. While they may "solve" your problem on the surface, they only ignore the problem, rather than fixing it. Never do this in production code.

The most likely cause is that you're on a network where there is a MITM corporate proxy. However legitimate these devices may be, they are effectively MITM devices.

What they do is that they will replace the original certificate with a certificate issued using their own internal CA, so as to be able to monitor the traffic.

If this device was legitimately set up by your network administrator, you should be able to get its CA certificate (in those circumstances, the CA certificate would typically be installed on all end-user machines centrally administered).

It's quite likely that, as a developer, you may have installed your own machine, and might not have the CA certificate installed. Ask your network administrator for that CA certificate, and install it with the certificates used by your browser and by curl within PHP (two different locations). Where the curl default location is may depend on the system you're using, but you can also configure it via `CURLOPT_CAINFO`.

Presumably, you're developing within a local network, but may possibly deploy that service on a different network when it's done. Make sure that this is configurable.

Comment: what about using a proxy? I use a ssh tunnel, for accessing facebook from my lan, which other wise has invalid certificate. So, I suggested that a proper fix would be using a proxy. You should add that to your answer to make it more complete. By the way, I completely agree with what you said.

Comment: @goldenparrot, sure an SSH tunnel would work, but that's just a loophole that's not very consistent with a tight security policy normally in place where MITM SSL proxy servers are used.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add these two lines for SSL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Comment: Disabling certificate verification introduces a MITM-attack vulnerability, which goes precisely against the reason why services like Facebook try to force HTTPS.

Comment: @Bruno From his question "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" and he need to do curl request

Comment: So, your solution to "I can't trust your identity" is "let's just ignore the fact that I was trying to verify your identity in the first place"...

Comment: I think There is no other solution, If certificate not trusted.